# Parse string description of timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

I get information about `timezone` in such `string format.`

```
 (UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius
```

Is it somehow possible to parse it into some **TimeZone object** in `Java with standard library` or external one?

Comment: yes it is possible.Could you show your code so we can help you

Comment: @therealprashant I just have this string and want convert it into time zone. No more code.

Comment: I know it is possible in imperative(regexp) way, but I would like some declarative approach.

Comment: Have a look at [TimeZone getTimeZone(String ID)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29). Seems this would do the job.

Comment: @SubOptimal It always return GMT timezone.

Comment: The timezone abbreviation must be a valid one. Replace `UTC` by `GMT`.

Comment: Even TimeZone.getTimeZone("(GMT+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius") returns GMT+00:00

Comment: Which is clear as the javadoc says `... or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00" ...`. You need to strip the timezone information from the other text. There is no build-in artificial intelligence which does if for you.

Comment: @SubOptimal Thank you. So the answer is that i need to extract content from brackets and use TimeZone.getTimeZone. It is a little bit imperative but acceptable. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you want to use the `TimeZone` afterwards you might either create a custom one

```
String input = "(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius";
// assuming the format is always fixed at the beginning
String timeZoneOffset = input.substring(4,10);
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + timeZoneOffset);
System.out.println("timeZone = " + timeZone);
```

**output (line wrapped)**

```
timeZone = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+02:00",offset=7200000,dstSavings=0,\
useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

You might get into trouble related to the daytime savings.

Or you create a lookup map with an entry for each offset (stripped down code snipped)

```
String input = "(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius";
// assuming the format is always fixed at the beginning
String timeZoneOffset = input.substring(4,10);

// needs to be initialized somewhere
Map<String, TimeZone> timeZones = new HashMap<>();
// you need to add all offsets
timeZones.put("+02:00", TimeZone.getTimeZone("EET"));

System.out.println("timeZone lookup = " + timeZones.get(timeZoneOffset));
```

**output (line wrapped)**

```
timeZone lookup = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="EET",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,\
useDaylight=true,transitions=123,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=EET,offset=7200000,\
dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,\
startDay=-,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,\
endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, as I know the support for the UTC is available by `ZoneId.of("UTC+02:00")` from Java 1.8 standard library. It combined with `LocalDateTime` should let me avoid the problems with daytime savings.